# Typescript: extending module in definition file

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Given [this definition file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/db87f8a0c18f5f8f58524daa81b9dc417492ea8e/koa/koa.d.ts), could anyone confirm to me that it is not possible to extend the exported `Request` interface since the namespace is not exported? If it is possible, I would appreciate any hints in the right direction :)

I tried the following in my `index.d.ts`, without success:

```
declare module 'koa' {
    namespace Koa {
        export interface Request {
            body: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you, Robin

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extend it you just have to redo the entire module declaration to do so.

koa.d.ts:

```js
declare module 'koa' {
    namespace Koa {
        export interface Request {
            body: string;
        }
    }
}
```

someOtherFile.d.ts:

```js
declare module 'koa' {
    namespace Koa {
        export interface Request {
            head: string;
        }
    }
}
```

useIt.ts:

```js
import {Koa} from 'koa';

let x : Koa.Request;

x.head;  // works just fine
```